# Preventing newlines in Text widget, but still proagate the event upwards?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

According to Effbot's Tkinterbook on [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm), I can prevent newlines from being inserted into a Text widget via this code:

```
text.bind("<Return>", lambda e: "break")
```

Which does work, but it prevents the `<Return>` event from reaching the parent form, which has its own `<Return>` binding that performs work on the Text widget and others.  What I want to do is catch events like `<Return>`, `<KP_Enter>`, etc, in the Text widget and prevent the newline from being inserted, but I still want that event to propagate upwards.  I can't find a good way of doing this, because Text widgets have no form of validation like Entry widgets (which is where this kind of work would normally be done).

I am thinking that if I override `<KeyPress>` and check `event.keycode` for `13`, I can skip the internal call to `::tk::TextInsert` and instead invoke whatever function internal to Tk is responsible for passing events up to the next elements in the bindtags, based on reading the TCL code in `text.tcl` in Python.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a small program that creates a text and parent widget with the `<return>` bindings so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: That would be hard....I've written some of my own wrapper code around Tkinter calls so I can draw my forms and widgets with less code.  Having to unravel that wrapper code for an example would take a bit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention bindtags, which sounds like you know what they are. Yet you also talk of events which propagate to their "parent form", which events don't normally do. The only time a `<return>` event will propagate to its parent is if the parent is in the bindtags. This will be true if the parent is the root window, but not for any other unless you explicitly add the parent to the bindtags.

When you do `return "break"` in a binding, you prevent other bindtags from acting on the event. There is no way to skip the immediately preceeding bindtag but allow additional bindtags to process the event.  And, there's no way (short of regenerating the event) to have other widgets that are not part of the bindtags process the event.

If you have a binding on a frame, and one on the text widget, and you want both to fire, just have your text widget binding call the code associated with the other binding. For example:

```
self.parent.bind("<Return>", self.validate_form)
Self.text.bind("<Return>", self.validate_form)
```

If `self.validate_form` returns "break", this should work as you expect.

Comment: Yup, mixing up the language a little bit.  I figured it out with a bit of cheating.  I catch the keycode of the pressed key in my existing validate function that I added, and if it's "13" for either of the two enter keys, then I can invoke specific bindtag in question or take additional actions.